Can i protect a route in Flask by IP or something like that?
've developed a small e-commerce using Flask, and in some of my routes, I display sensitive information related to a user's order, such as purchase details. However, while users can see the information rendered for them, I want to ensure that these routes are only accessible to the user who made the order.
Currently, there are some orders that can be generated by both non-registered users (guests) and registered users. The problem is that if someone knows the URL of an order page, they could potentially access that order's details, which I want to protect. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to secure these routes so that only the specific user who placed the order can view their information, even if they have the direct URL.
Some ideas passed on my mind to protect that route were:
-Use of a cookie session by X time after the order was generated
-Try to find some way using request origin IP
Any idea or libs about how can i handle the problem i try to solve

IP addresses are not reliable, multiple people might share the same IP address. Can you clarify what you are trying to do in a bit more detail? Your question is a bit cryptic.

You need an Authentication and Authorisation system - e.g. Flask-Security

But i already have an authentification and authorization system, that doesn't solve my problem
